# QGIS crashes when running Action to create new field

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, actions

I made a layer style with a python action with following code :

```py
def add_field(field_name, layer, field_type=QVariant.Invalid, field_length=0, field_precision=0, value=None, from_field=False):
    if layer.fields().indexFromName(field_name) != -1:
        return
    if not layer.isEditable():
        layer.startEditing()
    field = QgsField(field_name, field_type, len=field_length, prec=field_precision)
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([field])
    layer.updateFields()
    if value is not None:
        field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(field_name)
        if from_field:
            for feature in layer.getFeatures():
                layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), field_index, feature[value])
        elif QVariant(value).type() == field_type:
            for feature in layer.getFeatures():
                layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), field_index, value)
    layer.commitChanges()


layer = iface.activeLayer()

add_field("Test", layer, field_type=QVariant.String)
add_field("Message2", layer, field_type=QVariant.String, value="Message", from_field=True)
add_field("Type", layer, field_type=QVariant.String, value="Annotation")
add_field("Test2", layer, field_type=QVariant.String)
add_field("Test3", layer, field_type=QVariant.String)
add_field("Test4", layer, field_type=QVariant.String)
add_field("Test5", layer, field_type=QVariant.String)
```

it's meant to add a new field to my layer with possibility to choose the QgsField type, length, precision and if it has a same value for all features or the values of another existing field.

My test layer is a simple point layer from a Sqlite file with one string field "Message". I run the action in the Attribute Table. I checked all action scopes.

QGIS crashes with following message :

```
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   qgis_gui                               0x110090128 QgsAttributeTableModel::prefetchSortData(QString const&, unsigned long) + 776
1   qgis_gui                               0x11008a5e9 QgsAttributeTableFilterModel::setAttributeTableConfig(QgsAttributeTableConfig const&, bool) + 1273
2   qgis_gui                               0x1100abf2e QtPrivate::QFunctorSlotObject<QgsDualView::init(QgsVectorLayer*, QgsMapCanvas*, QgsFeatureRequest const&, QgsAttributeEditorContext const&, bool, bool)::$_15, 0, QtPrivate::List<>, void>::impl(int, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase*, QObject*, void**, bool*) + 142
3   QtCore                                 0x1112f9a95 void doActivate<false>(QObject*, int, void**) + 1157
4   qgis_core                              0x115618309 QgsVectorLayer::updateFields() + 1385
5   _core.so                               0x15da564ff meth_QgsVectorLayer_updateFields(_object*, _object*) + 95
```

EDIT : the action runs perfectly when executed from pyqgis with QgsAction.run. It seems to be an overloading problem from QGIS GUI but I can't say why...